# Porch remodel with improved electrical service

Tags: porch

I recently remodeled a porch and upgraded the electrical for just a few floodlights and plugs, probably less than 1400 watts.  I ran a 10/2 with a ground to this remodel, off of a 30 amp breaker at the main.  The wire size had to do with distance from the main.  I then installed a small subpanel on the porch with one 15 amp breaker.   I used 14/2 with ground throughout this project, with 15 amp plugs. 
Your thoughts

Answer (score 5):

Nope.  You need a 20A breaker at the main.

When you upsize wire for long distance, you **do not** also upsize the breaker.  There's no reason to; the long distance doesn't consume any additional amps, it consumes *volts*. Amps remain the same.

A 30A breaker is not legal on a circuit supplying 15A or 20A breakers, you can only have 30A receptacles on that.

If you really want to get 30A worth of use out of the #10 cable, then add a subpanel at the porch, and you can have 2 or more 15/20A circuits coming out of that sub.  You are allowed to install a 120V subpanel, and that requires a 3-wire connection.